# How to style the Simple_HTML_DOM output

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm getting images and their url with the following code using Simple HTML DOM Parser:

```
<?php
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
    $url = "http://www.tokyobit.com";
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($url);
    foreach($html->find('img') as $img){
        echo $img . "<br/>";
        echo $img->src . "<br/>";
    }
?>
```

But the output doesn't look so nice:

[image: output]
<sub>(source: [netdna-cdn.com](http://main.makeuseoflimited.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/homework-output.png))</sub>

So how can I style the outputs in CSS like with adding a class to each image and it's src.
My CSS:

```
.image-and-src {
    border: 2px solid #777;
}
```

So how can I add that class? : image-and-src

Comment: AND what do you want??

Comment: I have a feeling you are trying to pick up another website's images... **and** your code works as intended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $img){
    echo '<div class="img-and-src">';
    echo $img . "<br/>";
    echo $img->src . "<br/>";
    echo '</div>';
}
```

The two lines added to the code wraps the echo'd content in a div with your class while it loops.
Now you have the possibility to also wrap the text in a span, styling them both seperately.

If you want to add the class to just the image without styling the text, you could try @Ajeet Manral's answer :)

Comment: Remove the `</br>` after `echo $img->src` and add it after `echo </div>`, then it works for me thanks.

Comment: That would depend on your situation, `<div>` s are block level elements therefore will always push the next block below itself ;) otherwise you're probably floating the divs in which case you should reset it for a cleaner solution with less html markup ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $img){

        echo $img->src . "<br/>";
        echo '<img src="'.$img->src.'" width=100% height=100px><br/>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to make your own template

### a template file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Your title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Somebody's images</h1>
  <?php foreach($html->find('img') as $img) { ?>
    <!-- put some pretty looking html here  -->
  <?php } ?>
<body>
</html>
```

if you don't know about templates, then I suggest some research on the subject